# Creating Ising Hamiltonian with Qiskit

Tags: qiskit

How to create Ising Hamiltonian and implement it with qiskit (the output should be in the form of  `WeightedPauliOperator`) for the following problem:

$$
H = A \big(K - \sum_{i}^{N} t_i x_i \big)^2\\
x_i=\{0,1\}\\
t_i \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}\\
K\in \mathbb{N}\\
A \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}\\
$$

I want to choose any number of variables $x_i$, that the sum $\sum_{i}^{N} t_i x_i$ will equal exactly $K$.

Comment: These two threads can help: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11663/how-to-convert-qubo-problem-to-ising-hamiltonian and https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12001/how-to-build-a-circuit-for-simulation-of-a-simple-hamiltonian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Qiskit's new optimization module. This allows you to use `docplex` to build your model:

```
# required imports
from docplex.mp.model import Model
from qiskit.optimization.problems import QuadraticProgram
from qiskit.optimization.converters import QuadraticProgramToIsing

# specify problem
n = 3
a = 1.0
k = 2
t = range(1, n+1)

# build model with docplex
mdl = Model()
x = [mdl.binary_var() for i in range(n)]
objective = a*(k - mdl.sum(t[i]*x[i] for i in range(n)))**2
mdl.minimize(objective)

# convert to Qiskit's quadratic program
qp = QuadraticProgram()
qp.from_docplex(mdl)

# convert to Ising Hamiltonian
qp2ising = QuadraticProgramToIsing()
H, offset = qp2ising.encode(qp)
print('Offset:', offset)
print('Ising Hamiltonian:')
print(H.print_details())
```

> Offset: 4.5
>
> Ising Hamiltonian:
>
> IIZ   (-1+0j)
>
> IZI   (-2+0j)
>
> ZII   (-3+0j)
>
> IZZ   (1+0j)
>
> ZIZ   (1.5+0j)
>
> ZZI   (3+0j)

You can find some tutorials introducing the functionality here:
https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/optimization/index.html
or here
https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/tree/master/tutorials/optimization

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you please explain to me one more thing. To run optimization problem (for example with VQE algorithm) it is necessary to get the problem in the form of `WeightedPauliOperator`. What exactly this structure represent? And how `WeightedPauliOperator` is related to Ising Hamiltonian?

Comment: The `WeightedPauliOperator` is a possible way to represent an Ising Hamiltonian, e.g. in contrast to the `MatrixOperator`. If you want to use VQE or QAOA to actually approximate the ground state, then Qiskit does the translation for you and you can directly use the `MinimumEigenOptimizer` and give it a `QuadraticProgram`. See this tutorial on QAOA: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/optimization/3_minimum_eigen_optimizer.ipynb
For VQE, just pass VQE as a `MinimumEigenSolver` instead of QAOA.

Comment: This is late, but `QuadraticProgramToIsing()` is no longer included in the Qiskit library. Has it been obsolete?

Comment: @Alternative7 it has been moved to `QuadraticProgram().to_ising()` (https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-optimization/blob/12d63bcc491aa836a316cd9ddbcb75f8e37f595c/qiskit_optimization/problems/quadratic_program.py#L1011)

Comment: @StefanWoerner Thanks a lot!